# How to use Quasar with Scala under sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, quasar

I wish to use [Quasar](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/) in my SBT project. Since [Scala is not yet supported](https://github.com/puniverse/quasar/issues/45) the only viable option left is to have SBT compile some java classes that use of Quasar.

I tried putting

```
javaOptions += "-javaagent:PATH_TO_JAR/quasar-core-0.5.0.jar"
```

and

```
fork := true
```

as I read that for using e.g. JRebel one must insert both these statements into build.sbt

But it does not seem to work either as using a Quasarish class ([QuasarExample](https://github.com/maciejjaskowski/sbt-quasar-example/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/jaskowski/QuasarExample.java)) yields:

```
[error]    IllegalArgumentException: : Fiber class HelloWorldSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$1 has not been instrumented.  (Fiber.java:151)
[error] co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.<init>(Fiber.java:151)
[error] co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.<init>(Fiber.java:171)
[error] co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.<init>(Fiber.java:448)
```

A piece of code that's expected to be running without errors after successful instrumentation:

```
new Fiber<Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer run() throws SuspendExecution, InterruptedException {
        return 0;
    }
}.start();
```

See also [this repository](https://github.com/maciejjaskowski/sbt-quasar-example) for a starter.

Answer (score 5):

As per the comment from @mjaskowski, [Dou you plan to instrument bytecode produced by Scala compiler?](https://github.com/puniverse/quasar/issues/45), Scala is not a supported language yet.

> Short answer is: absolutely. Longer answer is, yes, but not very soon.
>   Scala is a very (very, very, very, very) complex language (oh my god,
>   it's so incredibly complex!), and it would take a long time to test
>   Quasar with the many (many-many-many) Scala features. Given the
>   relatively small number of Scala developers, and the heavy integration
>   costs, this may take some time. We do, however support Clojure (much
>   simpler integration), and will soon probably (or maybe we already do)
>   support Kotlin (trivial integration).

Follow along to see the possible ways to have the javaagent set up in sbt.

This is my first encounter with Quasar so the steps are really basic however they should give you a head start.

### Running Quasar's javaagent in JVM alone

It's only with the following command to be able to run Quasar's javaagent without any Scala/sbt's jars.

> java -cp
>   /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/jars/asm-util-5.0.1.jar:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/jars/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm/jars/asm-5.0.1.jar -javaagent:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/co.paralleluniverse/quasar-core/jars/quasar-core-0.5.0.jar
>   -help

It appears it's not self-contained and needs additional jars on the `CLASSPATH`.

### Running Quasar's javaagent with scala

The following command makes `scala` and Quasar's javaagent happy.

> scala -debug -usebootcp -toolcp
>   /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/jars/asm-tree-5.0.1.jar:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/jars/asm-util-5.0.1.jar:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/jars/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm/jars/asm-5.0.1.jar:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/jars/asm-analysis-5.0.1.jar
>   -J-javaagent:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/co.paralleluniverse/quasar-core/jars/quasar-core-0.5.0.jar

### Initial attempts to run Quasar with sbt

Add the necessary dependencies of Quasar in `build.sbt`:

```
val quasarDeps = Seq(
  "quasar-core",
  "quasar-actors",
  "quasar-galaxy"
)

libraryDependencies := quasarDeps.map("co.paralleluniverse" % _ % "0.5.0")
```

It boils down to augmenting `libraryDependencies` with necessary jars. I chose all available.

I checked in Scala `console` that the libraries are available.

```
➜  quasar-sbt  xsbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to quasar-sbt (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/quasar-sbt/)
> console
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import co.paralleluniverse.fibers._
import co.paralleluniverse.fibers._

scala> Fiber.DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE
res0: Int = 32
```

You will also have to add the java agent. Add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
// FIXME the path to quasar-core should be simpler
javaOptions in Test += "-javaagent:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/co.paralleluniverse/quasar-core/jars/quasar-core-0.5.0.jar"

fork in Test := true

// only needed for Specs2 so I could test the test setup
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.13" % Test

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")
```

`reload` the build changes.

```
> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to quasar-sbt (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/quasar-sbt/)
```

Write a test to make sure all's set up properly. I used the `HelloWorldSpec` from `[Specs2][2]` with some changes:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers._

class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {

  "Quasar" should {
    "Fiber.DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE defaults to 32" in {
      Fiber.DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE === 32
    }
  }
}
```

It's not a very extensive test, so tweak it for your needs. Save the file under `src/test/scala`.

Execute `test`.

```
> test
objc[27427]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[info] HelloWorldSpec
[info]
[info] Quasar should
[info] + Fiber.DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE defaults to 32
[info]
[info] Total for specification HelloWorldSpec
[info] Finished in 40 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jul 13, 2014 2:04:13 PM
```

It works!

Comment: That does not prove anything :(
Even I can run  co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE in scala console. I edited my question and added an example code to test on.

Comment: If it's a Scala project, why did you paste a Java code? I had to rewrite it to match.

Comment: We have no choice: Quasar does not support Scala.

Comment: How do you know that? Is there an official statement from the Quasar team? It'd be useful to add it to my answer or add a comment.

Comment: Scala is not yet supported by Quasar due to Scala's complexity: https://github.com/puniverse/quasar/issues/45

Comment: Btw. do you still claim that your solution solves my problem? ;)

Comment: Well, in some sense you could assume the answer is indeed offered and hence the problem is solved, but the solution is not in any way satisfactory. That's another problem :)